# How to remove excess newline characters from strings within a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

My intention is to remove unnecessary newline characters from strings inside of a DataFrame.

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['I like this product\n\nThe product is good']
dataf = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Original data:

```
I like this product

The product is good
```

I tried the following, which was not successful, since all of the newline characters were removed, whereas I wanted to keep one of them.

```
dataf['new'] = dataf.replace('\\n','', regex=True)
```

The result was this, all newline characters were removed:

```
I like this productThe product is good
```

The result I am trying to achieve is this:

```
I like this product
The product is good
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
dataf['new'] = dataf.replace(r'(\n)+', r'\n', regex=True)
```

The `+` indicates one or more occurrences of the preceding pattern, and however many there are, they will all be replaced by just one newline character.